# Integral of $\sin(\sqrt{x})$

Tags: trigonometry, integration

I need help finding the integral of $\sin(\sqrt{x})dx$. I have the answer here but would like to know how to get there.

Answer (score 10):

Use the substitution $t=\sqrt{x}$, and then use integration by parts.  From the substitution, you should get:

$$\int\sin\sqrt{x}dx=2\int t\sin (t) dt$$

Then, use integration by parts.  Let $u=t$ and $dv=\sin t$.  Then $du=dt$ and $v=-\cos t$, and we have:

$$\int t\sin (t) dt=-t\cos t +\int \cos (t) dt=\sin t -t\cos t=\sin\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x}\cos\sqrt{x}$$

and we have the solution:

$$\int\sin\sqrt{x}dx=2(\sin\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x}\cos\sqrt{x})$$

I hope this clears up the matter for you!

Answer (score 5):

$$J = \underbrace{\int \sin(\sqrt{x})dx = \int \sin(t) 2t dt }_{\sqrt{x} = t \implies x = t^2 \implies dx = 2t dt}$$
$$I = \int t \sin(t) dt = -\int t d(\cos(t)) = - \left(t \cos(t) - \int \cos(t) dt \right) = - t \cos(t) + \sin(t) + c$$
Hence, $$J = - 2t \cos(t) + 2\sin(t) + k = -2 \sqrt{x} \cos(\sqrt{x}) + 2 \sin(\sqrt{x}) + k$$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Use the substitution $\sqrt{x}=u$ or $x=u^2$ and then integration by parts.

$$\int \sin(\sqrt{x})dx = 2\int u\sin(u)du $$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $$\sin(\sqrt{x}) = \frac{\sqrt{x}\sin(\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}$$
and take $u=\sqrt{x}$, $2 du=\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$.