# How to integrate $\int x\sin {(\sqrt{x})}\, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I tried using integration by parts twice, the same way we do for  $\int \sin {(\sqrt{x})}$
but in the second integral, I'm not getting an expression that is equal to  $\int x\sin {(\sqrt{x})}$.

I let $\sqrt x = t$ thus,
$$\int t^2 \cdot \sin({t})\cdot 2t dt =  2\int t^3\sin(t)dt = 2[(-\cos(t)\cdot t^3 + \int 3t^2\cos(t))] = 2[-\cos(t)\cdot t^3+(\sin(t)\cdot 3t^3 - \int 6t \cdot \sin(t))]]$$

which I can't find useful.

Comment: Treat $\int 6t\cdot\sin(t)\;dx$ as if it's a separate problem.  (two more integrations by parts)

Comment: @anorton Two integrations by parts?

Comment: @DavidMitra Oh, duh.  Sorry--just one more integration by parts.  I was thinking of something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, indeed, continue as you did in the comments, treating $\int 6t\sin t \,dt\;$ as a separate integral, use integration by parts, and add (or subtract, if appropriate) that result to your earlier work, and you will end with an expression with no integrals remaining!:

$$\int t^2 \cdot \sin({t})\cdot 2t dt = $$

$$= 2[-\cos(\sqrt x) \cdot x(\sqrt x) + \sin(\sqrt x)\cdot 3x -(\cos(\sqrt x)\cdot6\sqrt x+\sin(\sqrt x)\cdot \sqrt x + \cos (\sqrt x))] + C$$

after substituting $\sqrt x$ for $t$, though I'd suggest finding a way to simplify (combining like terms, etc.)

Comment: always sound advice! +1

Answer (score 1):

Just continue your path of partial integration with the last integral ? The last integral is purely a cosine which is integrable and yields your sollution.

Comment: so I need a third partial integral?

Comment: From where I see it you are almost there, if you apply partial integration to the last integral (and eliminate t that way) you'll get a basic integral of the cosine

Comment: I get $\int 6t \sin(t) = \cos(t)\cdot 6t -[-(\sin(t)\cdot t) + \int \sin(t)] = \cos(t)\cdot 6t -[-(\sin(t)\cdot t) -\cos(t)]$ which still does not eliminate everything needs to be eliminated as far as I can see

Comment: oh wait, it is. I'm getting an expression with no integrals in $t$ terms. Could it be that I got there? Might this be the final answer? $2[-\cos(\sqrt x) \cdot x(\sqrt x) + \sin(\sqrt x)\cdot 3x -(\cos(\sqrt x)\cdot6\sqrt x+\sin(\sqrt x)\cdot \sqrt x + \cos (\sqrt x))]$

Answer (score 0):

you have done till this - $ 2[-\cos(t)\cdot t^3+(\sin(t)\cdot 3t^3 - \int 6t \cdot \sin(t))]]$

again use parts to get

$ 2[-\cos(t)\cdot t^3+(\sin(t)\cdot 3t^3 -  6(t(-\cos t) +\sin(t))$ =

$ 2[-\cos(t)\cdot t^3+(\sin(t)\cdot 3t^3 +  6(t(\cos t) -6\sin(t))$ .
giving you your answer .

just put $ \sqrt{x} = t $ and you are through.

Answer (score 0):

Integrating by parts, we get

if $n\ne-1,$

$$\int x^n\cos\sqrt xdx= \frac{x^{n+1}\cos\sqrt x}{n+1}+\frac1{2(n+1)}\int x^{n+\frac12}\sin\sqrt x dx$$

$$\int x^n\sin\sqrt xdx= \frac{x^{n+1}\sin\sqrt x}{n+1}-\frac1{2(n+1)}\int x^{n+\frac12}\cos\sqrt x dx$$

Putting $n=\frac12$ in the first integral,

$$\int x^\frac12\cos\sqrt xdx= \frac{x^{\frac12+1}\cos\sqrt x}{\frac12+1}+\frac1{2(\frac12+1)}\int x\sin\sqrt x dx$$

$$\implies \int x\sin\sqrt x dx=3\int x^\frac12\cos\sqrt xdx- 2x^{\frac12+1}\cos\sqrt x$$

Putting $n=0$ in the second integral,

$$\int \sin\sqrt xdx= \frac{x \sin\sqrt x}{1}-\frac1{2}\int x^{\frac12}\cos\sqrt x dx$$

$$\implies \int x^{\frac12}\cos\sqrt x dx= 2x \sin\sqrt x-2\int \sin\sqrt xdx$$

Now, $\int \sin\sqrt xdx$ can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271343/integral-of-sin-sqrtx)